# R - Merging two dataframe by text

Tags: r, text, merge

I have two datasets which I want to merge :

```
df1 <- data.frame( title = 
                     c("residence mozart", 
                       "les hesperides auteuil mirabeau",
                       "chaillot",
                       "jouvenet",
                       "retraite  dosne"))
                   
                   
df2 <- data.frame(title = c("terrasses mozart", "chaillot",
                  "villa jules janin", "retraites dosne"))
```

And I would like to have something like this :

```
1 residence mozart                  NA (or terrasses mozart)
2 les hesperides auteuil mirabeau   NA
3 chaillot                          chaillot
4 jouvenet                          NA
5 retraite  dosne                   retraites dosne
```

Here is what I did :

```
x = data.frame(title_df2 = matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(df1)))


for (i in nbr){
  x[i, ] <- grep(df1$title[i], df2$title, value = T)
}
```

It does not work at all ! Even though `grep(df1$title[5], df2$title, value = T)` works and return "chaillot"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```r
df1 <- data.frame( title = 
                     c("residence mozart", 
                       "les hesperides auteuil mirabeau",
                       "chaillot",
                       "jouvenet",
                       "retraite  dosne"))


df2 <- data.frame(title = c("terrasses mozart", "chaillot",
                            "villa jules janin", "retraites dosne"))
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

stringdist_left_join(x = df1, y = df2, method = "jw", distance_col = "d") %>% 
  filter(d < 0.25) %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = c("title.x" = "title"))
#> Joining by: "title"
#>                           title.x          title.y          d
#> 1                residence mozart terrasses mozart 0.23863636
#> 2                        chaillot         chaillot 0.00000000
#> 3                 retraite  dosne  retraites dosne 0.09206349
#> 4 les hesperides auteuil mirabeau             <NA>         NA
#> 5                        jouvenet             <NA>         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is very useful but may need some clarification if the user is not familiar, of how the distance is computed and that you have essentially chosen an arbitrary distance threshold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It really helped me ! I did not know the library fuzzyjoin but this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
a <-Vectorize(agrep, "pattern")(df1$title, df2$title, value=TRUE)
is.na(a)<- lengths(a) == 0
cbind(df1,df2_title=unlist(a, use.names = FALSE))
                            title       df2_title
1                residence mozart            <NA>
2 les hesperides auteuil mirabeau            <NA>
3                        chaillot        chaillot
4                        jouvenet            <NA>
5                 retraite  dosne retraites dosne
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `grep` returns a vector of length 0 when there is no match.

```
grep('a', 'hello', value = TRUE)
#character(0)
```

If we want to make use of the same `for` loop, make an adjustment in the code to return `NA` whereever there is no match

```
nbr <- seq_len(nrow(df1))
for (i in nbr){
  x[i, ] <- c(grep(df1$title[i], df2$title, value = TRUE), NA_character_)[1]
}
```

-output

```
x
#  title_df2
#1      <NA>
#2      <NA>
#3  chaillot
#4      <NA>
#5      <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, I did not know where what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you need a matching on each word of your strings within df1 title.

As used in your example, Grep will return an output only if there is a match on the full string.
In order to do that, you'll need to grep on possible words on df1 that are also contained in df2. This can be achieved by implementing an or condition on the full word contained in each string.

```
nbr <- 1:nrow(x)
for (i in nbr){
  pattern <- paste("\\b",unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$title[i]), " ")), "\\b", collapse = "|", sep = "") # here you create a regex expression whereby you can check if one of the words contained in 1 is also in df2. the \\b \\b escape makes sure that there is a full match on the single word.

  fitInDataFrame <- grep(pattern, as.character(df2$title), value = T) # here you grep on the constructed regex expression
  
  x[i, ] <- ifelse(length(fitInDataFrame) == 0, NA, fitInDataFrame)
}
```

Here the output:

```
> x
         title_df2
1 terrasses mozart
2             <NA>
3         chaillot
4             <NA>
5  retraites dosne
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It helped me understand what went wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `left_join(df1, df2, by = c('title' = 'title'), keep = TRUE)`, specifying keep = TRUE so it doesn't drop df2's join column.

Or, for this particular case, you could do this:

```
df1$newcol <- ifelse(df1$title %in% df2$title, df1$title, NA)
```

This adds a new column to df1 which is filled out by going through each title in df1, checking if that title is in df2, if so writing that title in the second column and if not writing NA in that row of the second column. You could choose to put something else there instead, like:

```
df1$newcol <- ifelse(df1$title %in% df2$title, 'Title in DF2', 'Not in DF2')
```